# Craft is not installed yet with a REDIS error

Tags: error, redis

Our website is on the latest version of Craft 3.4, using REDIS (redis_version: 4.0.9) for Sessions and Caching.
Today the website stopped working with the well-known "Craft is not installed yet".

storage/logs/web.log contains the following lines:

```
There was a problem fetching the info row: Redis error: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.

Redis command was: SET CV-PROD9350e89e77a3b08b9480b6f648d34509 a:2:{i:0;s:23:"5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1";i:1;N;} PX 3600000

2021-03-26 12:39:55 [-][-][e0mfa29m7jagmbfurqnbqitptr][error][yii\db\Exception] yii\db\Exception: Redis error: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but it is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled, because this instance is configured to report errors during writes if RDB snapshotting fails (stop-writes-on-bgsave-error option). Please check the Redis logs for details about the RDB error.

Redis command was: SET CV-PROD9350e89e77a3b08b9480b6f648d34509 a:2:{i:0;s:23:"5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1";i:1;N;} PX 3600000 in /data/www/xxx/web/xxx.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-redis/src/Connection.php:821
```

Any ideas what is causing this?
Is there any Craft config I could set to avoid it?

Modifying the REDIS config is an option, but I would prefer solving this via Craft's config.

Comment: What version of Redis are you using?

Comment: redis_version: 4.0.9, also updated the question above

Comment: It seems more like a Redis configuration/permissions error to me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots

Comment: Yes, I also think that by now... I try to solve it with the provider